# Does AWS Autoscaling marks "stopped" instance as unhealty and spins a new instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I am working on building a quick start and trying to understand below statement from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html

"If your instance is in an Auto Scaling group, the Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling service marks the stopped instance as unhealthy, and *may* terminate it and launch a replacement instance. For more information, see Health Checks for Auto Scaling Instances in the Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling User Guide."

Can someone help cases that may lead to termination or is it always a termination?

Comment: Anytime an ASG sees that an instance is unhealthy, the instance will be terminated. It can be as part of an ELB health check or a custom health check. So, if you stop an EC2 instance that is in an ASG, auto scaling group will see that the instance is "Unhealthy" (meaning the instance can't be reached) and terminate the instance. A new EC2 instance is created instead. Anytime an ASG sees that an instance is unhealthy, the instance will be terminated.

Comment: It's not clear from the documentation why they use "may" instead of "will", but one possibility is that you are using custom health checks and you are reporting that the instance is healthy even though it is stopped. I would assume that in that case Auto Scaling sees the instance as healthy and will not schedule it for termination and replacement, even though it is stopped.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.